# binary search from a file

Tags: java, binary-search

how can I search a data using binary search? When if statement begins, the program goes to IOException block. It seems that it doesn't try to read the file.

```
public void busquedaDicotomica1(String clave)
{
    String lectura1=null, lectura2=null ;
    long posicion;
    long tamaño;
    long midValue;
    boolean valido = true;
    try
    {
        rafObj = new RandomAccessFile("indice1.ind","r");
        tamaño = rafObj.length();
        midValue = tamaño/2;
        rafObj.seek(midValue);
        if(clave.equalsIgnoreCase(rafObj.readUTF()))
        {

            System.out.println("ok");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
     }
    catch(EOFException eoe)
    {}
    catch(FileNotFoundException nfe)
    {
        VentanaPrincipal.setErrorText(dialogo);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        VentanaPrincipal.setErrorText(ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is file indice1.ind exist and is in classpath?

Comment: Yes it exists. However, i'm not sure about "midValue = tamaño/2". Because that position is not pointing at the beginin of the registry.

Comment: Well a binary search require a sorted collection. Is your file sorted? Also, I'm not sure in java, but a file stream might not allow seek operations.

Comment: yes, it is sorted, but I wouldn't like to have to load the hole file into collection because it means that I had to read the hole file.

Comment: what is the message in the ioexception?

Comment: You're trying to read a string from an arbitrary point in the file. Are you getting a UTFDataFormatException?